# Storyboard segue causes AVAudioEngine to crash

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am working with an AVAudioUnitSampler that is attached to an AVAudioEngine within my app. I've gotten everything to work well except when I segue out of the view controller that the sampler is instantiated in. I get a crash with an error that says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: outputNode'

I'm guessing that this is because the engine is getting interrupted somehow when I segue back to my previous VC, not sure!

I've tried to stop the engine and also the sequencer inside of viewWillDisappear, but it still crashes.

If I use a UIButton show segue to the previous VC,it sort of works, but I get a crash with an unwind segue and with the current navigation bar segue.

I'm a newbie, so hopefully I've explained this well enough!

I am getting to this VC from a segue triggered from a table view on the previous VC.

Here is the code for the VC in question:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var musicView: UIImageView!

    let allSounds = SoundBankOnAndOff()
    var currentSoundFile: OnandOff?
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        setupSequencer()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        engine.stop()
        sequencer.stop()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        descriptionLabel.text = exercises[myIndex]
        musicView.image = musicNotes[myIndex]
        engine = AVAudioEngine()
        sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

        engine.attach(sampler)
        engine.connect(sampler, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        loadSF2PresetIntoSampler(preset: 0)
        startEngine()
        setSessionPlayback()
    }

    func setSessionPlayback() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try
                audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with:
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        } catch {
            print("couldn't set category \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("category is active")
        } catch {
            print("couldn't set category to active \(error)")
            return
        }
    }

    func startEngine() {
        if engine.isRunning {
            print("audio engine has already started")
            return
        }

        do {
            try engine.start()
            print("audio engine started")
        } catch {
            print("oops \(error)")
            print("could not start audio engine")
        }
    }

    var sequencer:AVAudioSequencer!

    func setupSequencer() {
        let allSounds = SoundBankOnAndOff()
        let currentSoundFile = allSounds.list[myIndex]
        self.sequencer = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: engine)

        let options = AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions.smfChannelsToTracks

        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mid", subdirectory: "On & Off MIDI") {
            do {
                try sequencer.load(from: (currentSoundFile.soundFile), options: options)
                print("loaded \(fileURL)")
            } catch {
                print("something messed up \(error)")
                return
            }
        }
        sequencer.prepareToPlay()
    }


    func play() {
        if sequencer.isPlaying {
            stop()
        }

        sequencer.currentPositionInBeats = TimeInterval(0)

        do {
            try sequencer.start()


        } catch {
            print("cannot start \(error)")
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        sequencer.stop()
    }

    func loadSF2PresetIntoSampler(preset:UInt8)  {
        guard let bankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Pad Sounds", withExtension: "sf2") else {
            print("could not load sound font")
            return
        }

        do {
            try sampler.loadSoundBankInstrument(at: bankURL, program: preset,bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB),bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB))
        } catch {
            print("error loading sound bank instrument")
        }
    }



    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.currentTitle == "PLAY"{
            play()
            sender.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
        } else if sender.currentTitle == "STOP" {
            sender.setTitle("PLAY", for: .normal)

            stop()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func BackButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToDetailVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try disconnecting the node inputs and outputs before segue? There's also a 'detach' for every 'attach'.

Comment: Hi! I added the code engine.disconnectNodeInput(engine.mainMixerNode)
       engine.disconnectNodeOutput(engine.mainMixerNode)
       engine.stop() in my viewWillAppear and now I get the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: !IsRunning()'     ...maybe we're on to something here.

Comment: When using I/O libraries like audio engines (that are typically async), you need to release resources, etc, before killing the objects associated with it. Take a look at the doc for AVAudioEngine and the other AV classes you're using. A lot times if something is running without being stopped, it could cause problems. http://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine

Comment: Right on. Thanks for the reply. I have been trying to read this documentation and understand... Is there another way I can do that? I have tried to disconnect the nodes and stop the Audio Engine in viewWillDisappear, and it is still crashing.

Comment: What does it say in the stack trace?

Comment: libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_qos:
    0x114b40ef0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000176, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000176 
    0x114b40ef5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x114b40ef8 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x114b40efa <+10>: jae    0x114b40f04               ; <+20>
    0x114b40efc <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x114b40eff <+15>: jmp    0x114b3a7cd               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x114b40f04 <+20>: retq   
    0x114b40f05 <+21>: nop    
    0x114b40f06 <+22>: nop    
    0x114b40f07 <+23>: nop

Comment: Is this what you mean? cerror_nocancel 0x114b40f04 <+20>

Comment: Ok, I don't think it has anything to do with detach, etc. I just created a simple mp3 player using AVKit library like you, and I'm able to segue to another view controller even while the mp3 is playing. I can post my code that works if you want. Maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference. You're segueing back. I can modify my code to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'm trying to work with the code you displayed here... not entirely sure how to integrate it into mine 100%, but I'll keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is similar to yours and doesn't crash when segueing or unwinding:

```
class MP3PlayerVC: UIViewController {

    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    let distortion = AVAudioUnitDistortion()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioEngine.attach(audioPlayer)
        audioEngine.attach(distortion)
        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayer, to: distortion, format: nil)
        audioEngine.connect(distortion, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "mp3") {

            let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

            if let audioFile = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: url) {

                if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
                    audioPlayer.stop()
                    audioEngine.stop()
                } else {

                    audioPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

                    do {
                        try audioEngine.start()

                        audioPlayer.play()

                    } catch {
                        print("something went wrong")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This led me to being able to fix my issue. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Terry, what was the fix you determined from this?

Comment: Hi @TheNeil, I figured out that I needed to start the audio player right before the segue button is tapped. It os a bit of a silly workaround, but I play a 1 millisecond long silence file when the button is tapped, and now it doesn't crash!

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the reply! Does feel like a workaround that must be avoidable. I encountered a similar issue and determined that the best approach is to explicitly **set anything using the audio engine to nil during the start of `deinit`**, because otherwise, iOS deallocates the audio engine _first_, causing that error. For me, it was a sequencer triggering the error, but sounds like the same thing. More details on a fix available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036260/avaudiosequencer-causes-crash-on-deinit-segue-required-condition-is-false-out/58036261#58036261

Comment: Great, thanks for the follow up. I’ll definitely check this out.