# AVAudioSequencer Causes Crash on Deinit/Segue: 'required condition is false: outputNode'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

The below code causes a crash with the following errors whenever the object is deinitialized (e.g. when performing an unwind segue back to another ViewController):

> required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:4474:GetDefaultMusicDevice: (outputNode)]
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: outputNode'

The `AVAudioSequencer` is the root of the issue, because the error ceases if this is removed.

How can this crash be avoided?

```
class TestAudioClass {
    
    private var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine
    private var sampler: AVAudioUnitSampler
    private var sequencer: AVAudioSequencer
    
    init() {
        self.audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        self.sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
        audioEngine.attach(sampler)
        audioEngine.connect(sampler, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        self.sequencer = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: audioEngine)
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestMusic", withExtension: "mid") {
            do {
                try sequencer.load(from: fileURL, options: AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions())
            } catch {
                print("Error loading sequencer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        sequencer.prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This crash can be confusing, and may also output no error message whatsoever to the console if the sequencer's content hasn't been loaded yet. Very unhelpful!

The `AVAudioSequencer` is indeed the cause of the issue. To fix it, make the sequencer an implicitly unwrapped optional (i.e. add `!` to its type) and add explicit instructions to stop & remove it during `deinit`, *before* the rest of the object is deinitialized.

The fixed code is as follows (take note of the `deinit` method especially):

```
class TestAudioClass {

    private var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine
    private var sampler: AVAudioUnitSampler
    private var sequencer: AVAudioSequencer!

    init() {
        self.audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        self.sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
        audioEngine.attach(sampler)
        audioEngine.connect(sampler, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        self.sequencer = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: audioEngine)
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestMusic", withExtension: "mid") {
            do {
                try sequencer.load(from: fileURL, options: AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions())
            } catch {
                print("Error loading sequencer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        sequencer.prepareToPlay()
    }

    deinit {
        sequencer.stop()
        sequencer = nil
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!